# Is it possible to make a character putting my own face or some other specific face into it?

Tags: modeling

Is it possible to make a character putting my own face or some other specific face into it?
I mean i wanna see myself as a 3d character.

Comment: Yes. A common way to do it is called 'projection painting'. Have a look to https://www.google.fr/webhp?ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=0kUsWNnhG8TI8ge2q4WoDQ&gws_rd=cr#q=blender+projection+painting&tbm=vid&*

Comment: If you mean: use a 3d head model and change its appearance (textures) to make it look like different people... it is possible as in the above comment, but obviously the 3d shape of different people's head, although similar, it is quite different. Your "head texture" will look much like "you" only on a 3d head model that is much like "your real head". A 3d scan could put those things together, scanning both the shape and the "texture" of a particular head.